# Does ARC Welder still work?

Tags: android-emulator

I recently came to know that there is an official Android emulator available  which is developed by Google - Arc Welder. But when I try to follow the steps mentioned, I'm ending up with getting this error message:

```
Graphics Feature Status
Canvas: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
Flash: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled    
Flash Stage3D: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
Flash Stage3D Baseline profile: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
Compositing: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
Multiple Raster Threads: Disabled
Native GpuMemoryBuffers: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
Out-of-process Rasterization: Disabled
Hardware Protected Video Decode: Disabled
Rasterization: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
Skia Deferred Display List: Disabled
Skia Renderer: Disabled
```

Can anyone help me with this error?

Answer (score 3):

ARC Welder is dead.

If you want to run Android apps on Chrome OS there now official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/chrome-os/intro) (including emulator in the Android SDK) on supporting the Play Store in Chrome OS.

The closest I know of to a formal statement regarding ARC is [this article from ArsTechnica about Play Store on Chrome OS](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2016/05/the-play-store-comes-to-chrome-os-but-not-the-way-we-were-expecting/) where a Google manager explains that the ARC method was limited by not passing the Android compatibility tests, which meant more work for developers to get their app working, as well as not supporting Android NDK, which meant games wouldn't work either.

While the initial promise of [ARC](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2015/04/googles-arc-opens-up-to-developers-runs-android-apps-on-most-desktop-oses/) technology was to use the multi-platform [Native Client](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client) feature in Chrome it seems that it wasn't up to the job and Native Client itself is getting phased out.

If you still want to try to use ARC Welder in Chrome you'll have to find/use the last version of Chrome which supported it. This post in StackOverflow on
[ARC welder for chrome is not launching properly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47687585/295004) from 2017 may give some idea of when it last worked.

As I stated in [Chrome OS current support for Android via containers](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/201817/3573) Google is going forward with containers on Chrome OS to support Android apps (ARC++). While current ARC++ support for Android apps still needs improvement, enough is compatible with existing Android apps (including games) for the Play Store on ChromeOS to be in the stable release of some Chromebooks.