# What is Android OS in context of Chrome OS?

Tags: adb, linux, shell, terminal

What kind of operating system is Android? I've tried using other file types, but not any of them work: `.ios`, `.img`, `.exe`, `.pkg`.

My terminal needs a password which is `chromeos-setdevpasswd`. Yet, when I use it with `sudo sh`, it times out and resets its own pass.

As I know, I have to take out the data strips screw to stop it from timing out. I don't know if that's why I can't use certain commands because I've already been to root status in `crosh`.

Comment: Please read at least the first sentence on the Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system) it answers your question what OS Android is. Note that Chrome OS is not Android, it also comes from Google but is totally different from Android.

Comment: For a little more context about how Android is run inside of ChromeOS see: [What differences are there now adays from Chrome OS and the Android OS?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/201801/3573)